# Python stop the repeat of y axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using matplotlib to print a set of data with the same x-axis, I don't know why the plot is like this :
[image: repeat y axis]

while i want something like this :
[image: right plot]

The data is a csv file like this:

```
151.804, 99.1528, 71.0553, 55.8169, 45.9793
154.364, 96.0074, 71.0738, 55.8294, 45.9415
155.047, 97.1143, 70.7169, 55.8803, 46.0551
154.578, 96.7851, 71.0087, 55.7027, 45.9939
154.891, 97.0992, 71.2066, 55.8848, 46.0346
```

And I'm using the python code below to read and plot it:

```
file = open (csvFilePath)
csvreader = csv.reader(file)
rows = []
for row in csvreader:
    rows.append(row)
    rowcount+= 1
pointLights = [x*50 for x in range(1,6)]
fileNames = ['one','two','three','four', 'five']

for row in rows :       
        plt.plot(pointLights,row, label = fileNames[indexCsvFile]) 
        indexCsvFile +=1

plt.show()
```

Comment: can you add the data set you are trying , and the code you are using to plot this ?

Comment: looks like your data are strings instead of numerical types like float or int.

Comment: you are right, thanks !